# calculating limit with a variable

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to calculate this limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(x-1)^4-4x+8}{(x-b)^2}
$$
Because the numerator is a polynomial it is continuous and has limits. Of course there will be no limit if $(x-b)^2=0$. Thus:
$$
\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(x-1)^4-4x+8}{(x-b)^2} = \frac{1}{(2-b)^2} \qquad b \neq 2
$$

Yet when I check the solution in Wolfram Alpha I get this answer:
$$
 \frac{1}{(b-2)^2}
$$
This is the Wolfram query: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E2+((x-1)%5E4-4x%2B8)%2F(x-b)%5E2

Why is it different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that

$$(2-b)^2=[-1 \times (b-2)]^2 $$

$$ (-1)^2(b-2)^2=(b-2)^2$$

Comment: Nice! So my solution would be fine as well?

Comment: Yes of course !